# Signals and inheritance: pattern to avoid parent triggering signals too early

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a model class that emits a signal when changed:

```
class Foo(QObject):

  has_changed = pyqtSignal()
  
  def update_foo(self, ...):
    ...
    self.has_changed.emit()
```

Now I want to extend this model to include more features.

```
class FooDeluxe(Foo):

  def update_foo(self, ...):
    super().update_foo()  # emits has_changed even though FooDeluxe not ready
    ...
    self.has_changed.emit()
```

The problem is that when I call the parent's `update_foo`, it triggers `has_changed` even though `FooDeluxe` is not completely updated yet.

I am pretty sure this is a rather common situation and I was wondering what is the best practice pattern to overcome it. Having a different signal for `FooDeluxe` beats the purpose of inheritance and wouldn't scale up very well. We could also make sure signals are always emitted in a separate function like

```
class Foo(QObject):
  ...
  def _update_foo(self, ...):
    ...
    return has_changed
  def update_foo(self, ...):
    if self._update_foo(...)
      self.has_changed.emit()

class FooDeluxe(Foo):
  ...
  def _update_foo(self, ...):
    super()._update_foo(...)
    ...
    return has_changed
  def update_foo(self, ...):
    if self._update_foo(...):
      self.has_changed.emit()
```

I think this would work, and if we have total control of `Foo` this is probably not to bad of a solution, but it supposed a particular implemention for the base model class, of which we may not have control.

What are the standard patterns for this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, Qt doesn't provide a way to temporarily mute a *specific* signal, which would give the ideal solution. There is [QObject.blockSignals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals), but that has the potentially nasty side-effect of muting some other signals may still be needed. The specific signal could be disconnected and re-connected, but then you would need a way to programmatically discover all the slots that were previously connected - and Qt does not proivde an API for that either.

Comment: I suppose a simple solution would be to add a keyword-only `quiet=False` argument to `update_foo` which the caller can use to explictly mute the `has_changed` signal.

Comment: @ekhumoro Still requires control of the base class, but less verbose than my proposal.

Comment: If you really can't change the base-class at all, then emitting a different signal would appear to be Qt's own preferred solution. For example, `QStandardItemModel` has an `itemChanged` signal in addition to the inherited index-based signals. I don't really see how *in general* defining different signals and methods in subclasses necessarily defeats the purpose of inheritance or is in any way less scalable. You'd need to demonstrate that with a specific example - otherwise, it's fair to assume YAGNI applies.